# Does R 4.0.0. make it possible to define foo"(...)" operators, similar to the newly introduced r"(...)" syntax?

Tags: r, syntax, interpreter, rawstring

R 4.0.0 brings in a new syntax for raw strings:

```
r"(raw string here can contain anything except the closing sequence)"
```

But this same construct in R 3.x.x produced a syntax error:

> Error: unexpected string constant in "r"(asdasd)""

Does it mean that the interpreter was changed in R 4.0.0. ?
And if so - does R 4.0.0. provide a mechanism to define custom functions like `foo"()"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible at the moment (nor would I anticipate it becoming possible anytime soon).

Here's the NEWS item:

> There is a new syntax for specifying raw character constants similar to the one used in C++: `r"(...)"` with `...` any character sequence not containing the sequence `)"`. This makes it easier to write strings that contain backslashes or both single and double quotes. For more details see `?Quotes`.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html

Then from `?Quotes`:

> Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar to
>     the one used in C++: `r"(...)"` with `...` any character
>     sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence
>     `)"`. The delimiter pairs `[]` and `{}` can also be
>     used, and `R` can be used in place of `r`. For  additional
>     flexibility, a number of dashes can be placed between the opening quote
>     and the opening delimiter, as long as the same number of dashes appear
>     between the closing delimiter and the closing quote.

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/man/Quotes.Rd

Here's the (`git` mirror of the SVN patch of the) commit where this functionality was added:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/8b0e58041120ddd56cd3bb0442ebc00a3ab67ebc

Comment: Thanks and +1, specially for including the commit. Based on the code there it seems like indeed the parser was adjusted (`src/main/gram`), but only in a way that allows for `r` or `R` to be used before the quote.